# Get the line height of a RenderObject of a RichText in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to get the actual line height of a RichText.
This can easily be achieved if there is only one line of text, as the size of the RichText's RenderObject will be the text's too.
But if it is multi-line, this of course doesn't work anymore.

Comment: this is what you need: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderParagraph-class.html

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry but I don't see that information on that class

Comment: this maybe https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderParagraph/getBoxesForSelection.html ?